# sqoop script error "... is not a valid DFS filename"

Tags: sqoop

*running this in a Linux environment via putty from windows.

I have a sqoop script, trying to copy a table from oracle to hive. I get an error  regarding my destination path...`/hdfs://myserver/apps/hive/warehouse/new_schema/new_table is not a valid DFS filename`

Can anyone please tell me if my destination path looks correct? I am not trying to setup a file, I just want to copy a table from oracle to hive and put it in a scheme that already exists in hive. Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

sqoop import \
-Dmapred.map.child.java.opts='-Doracle.net.tns_admin=. -    Doracle.net.wallet_location=.' \
-files  $WALLET_LOCATION/cwallet.sso,$WALLET_LOCATION/ewallet.p12,$TNS_ADMIN/sqlnet.ora,$TNS_ADMIN/tnsnames.ora \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:/@MY_ORACLE_DATABASE \
--table orignal_schema.orignal_table \
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--hive-import \
--hive-table new_schema.new_table \
--num-mappers 1 \
--hive-overwrite \
--mapreduce-job-name my_sqoop_job \
--delete-target-dir \
--target-dir /hdfs://myserver/apps/hive/warehouse/new_schema.db \
--create-hive-table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's causing your that error is the "/" before your HDFS path. The correct path should be:

```sh
--target-dir hdfs://myserver/apps/hive/warehouse/new_schema.db
```

Also, always make sure the hostname is correct, to avoid further errors.